# PHP - mb_strlen, or strlen are returning 0 even though the string is growing in length

Tags: php, string, for-loop

The reference to mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8') here does not work.

```
<?php
  function listFolderFiles($dir,$str){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $matches;
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
      preg_match('/(html)$/',$ff,$matches);
      if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
          $str .= listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff,$str);
        } else if(count($matches) > 0) {
          if (mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8') > 0) {
            $str .= ','.$dir.'/'.$ff;
          } else {
            $str .= $dir.'/'.$ff;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return $str;
  }
  echo listFolderFiles('index','');
?>
```

When I 'echo mb_strlen($str,'utf-8)' I get the correct length.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: what is $str when mb_strlen does nothing?

Comment: $str is a string containing a list of files. $str concatenates new files to itself. So it's length is always changing.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You answered what you want $str to be. Before you call `mb_strlen` add `var_dump($str, mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8'));` and then tell us what $str is when mb_strlen return 0

Comment: `string(0) ""
int(0)
string(81) "index/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.html"
int(81)
string(109) "index/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.html,index/pages/home/_home.html"
int(109)
string(261) "index/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.html,index/pages/home/_home.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.htmlindex/pages/blog/_blog.html,index/pages/home/_home.html,index/pages/home/_self/images/images_.html"
int(261)
string(143149) "index/pages/blog/_blog.h...`

Comment: Perfect mb_strlen works

Answer (score 0):

It was actually, concatenating the recursive call which was causing the string to duplicate and concatenate each time a new directory was scanned. So I removed `$str .= listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff,$str);` -- and it's fixed

```
<?php
  function listFolderFiles($dir,$str){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $matches;
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
      preg_match('/(html)$/',$ff,$matches);
      if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
          $str = listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff,$str);
        } else if(count($matches) > 0) {
          if (strlen($str) == 0) {
            $str .= $dir.'/'.$ff;
          } else {
            $str .= ','.$dir.'/'.$ff;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return $str;
  }
  echo listFolderFiles('index','');
?>
```